# Fastest way to select the longest cell

Tags: programming, notebooks

I'm trying to learn low-level notebook programming and I have a question.

Is there faster way to select the longest cell in a notebook than this:

```
NB = CreateDocument[
      ExpressionCell[#, "Input"] & /@ {"cell 1", Column@{"cell", "2"}, "cell 3"}]
pos = Position[#, Max @@ #][[ 1, 1]] &@
              ReplaceAll[CellSize, (# // AbsoluteOptions) & /@ Cells[NB]][[ All, 2]]

SelectionMove[Cells[NB][[ pos]], All, Cell]
```

Comment: Longest means the `String` Content? or if cell options are the same, `ByteCount` maybe  useful after NotebookRead `CellObject`?

Comment: @HyperGroups Well, it does not matter now if it is going about height of cell or strign length. As You see I've used `AbsoluteOptions` and `ReplaceAll`, what I want is to make the code simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you want has been implemented by AbsoluteOptions. You can ask the value of a specific option using AbsoluteOptions. Your code then looks like this

```
pos = Position[#, Max @ #][[1, 
     1]] &@(AbsoluteOptions[#, CellSize][[1, 2, 2]] & /@ Cells[NB])
```

-> 2

I have also taken the liberty of selecting the second elements of the CellSize option values while doing the map, rather than selecting them afterwards. I've also written Max@# instead of Max@@# as the latter must be slower.

Comment: @Kuba, ah, I didn't realize it was you again :). I'm glad to see you are using Cells in this nice way :). You're welcome.